# Cufon is not working with Japanese text

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, cufon

I am getting some weird situation here. I have a MVC view, where I have applied cufon script for `h1` tag something like this:

```
Cufon.replace('h2.title-1', { fontFamily: 'TheSansBold-BoldPlain' });
```

This replacement is working fine with the english language, but when text is Japanese it's not working. Why I am getting this issue? Is there anyway to generalize this replacement to all the language, not just english or japanese.

Answer (score 2):

The font probably does not support the Japanese character set. I suggest you choose another font and make sure the font does support Japanese.